# What does a program executed by a process inherit?

Tags: c, inheritance, process, pipe, fork

A forked process obviously has the same environment with the parent.
Then a new program is executed in the child.
Does the program inherit the variables/enviroment of the child?

For example if there is a pipe fd[2] in the child, can I make a straight reference to it in the new program executed by the child?
Any ideas are worthy
Thanks!

Comment: [`man execve`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: In general, file descriptors remain across the exec unless (unless FD_CLOEXEC is set, which should not happen by default for a file descriptor opened via`pipe`)

Comment: @WilliamPursell If the program is executed with execl, does the program inherit anything from the process? –

Comment: There is no "inheritance" with `exec` because `exec` doesn't create a new process. If there is a new process, it was previously created with `fork`. What `exec` does is replace the executable image -- the program code and data -- with a new image.